# Getting value of fields on submit

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I have built a form using angular-formly.  Visually, all is looking and behaving well.  I am having trouble getting the value of the various fields within the form on submit (so that I can pass them to various calls to save the data).

Here is my code:

```
vm.occupationInfoFields = [
    {
        key: 'occupation',
        type: 'occupationSelect'
    }
];

<form ng-submit="vm.onSubmit()" name="vm.occupationInfoForm" novalidate>
    <div class="panel__body" style="padding: 15px; border-top: 1px solid gainsboro">
        <formly-form model="vm.occupationInfo" fields="vm.occupationInfoFields" form="vm.occupationInfoForm">
            <button type="submit"  class="btn">SUBMIT</button>
        </formly-form>
    </div>
</form>
```

Within the `OnSubmit` function, I have tried getting the value of this field from the `vm.occupationInfoForm` but nothing is jumping out at me.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I was expecting something like this to work but it returned `Undefined`:
`vm.occupationInfoForm.occupation`

EDIT 2:
I should have specified that I am having trouble accessing only the fields that use the type listed above (occupationSelect).  If I have a field that uses the normal INPUT type (or a custom type that extends INPUT), the value is added to the model once I modify the field and thus I have access to it.  However, when I change the selected value for the occupationSelect it does not get added to the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained on [the issue on github](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly-website/issues/71)

> The values are assigned to the model that you pass in. So instead of vm.occupationInfoForm.occupation, your values will be on vm.occupationInfo.occupation.

Comment: Thanks for the double reply :)  I should have also mentioned that I am only seeing this problem with my occupationSelect keys.  If I have a normal input field (or a new type that I created that extends the input type), the values are being added to the model with no problem and I can easily reference them.  But when I change the selected value in the dropdown...the doesn't get added to the model and thus I cannot access it.

Comment: Could you please create an example of this behavior? http://help.angular-formly.com

Comment: Bah, I suck.  I realized that I didn't have the ng-model setup correctly for this type.  Once I updated the value within this type it is updating the model correctly with the selected value.  Thanks for the help.